# PHP: what is the easiest way to dump class constants into array

Tags: php

I'm having a class with a list of constants. I want something like `get_object_vars` to dump constants into array. What is the simpliest way to do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will require use of the Reflection class:

```
function getClassConstants($class) {
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass(
        is_object($class) ? get_class($class) : $class
    );
    return $reflection->getConstants();
}
// usage: $constants = getClassConstants('myClass');
//        $constants = getClassConstants($myClassObjectInstance);
```

or you can implement it as a method in your class by passing it `$this` instead of an argument

**Documentation**

PHP's Reflection class- https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

PHP's ReflectionClass::getConstants -
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php